# Add a random avatar to new user in Django UserCreationForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to choose a random avatar from the database and add it to a user's account when they click on the 'Sign up' button on the registration page. I tried implementing this in my view but I keep getting the following error.

```
>  if file and not file._committed: AttributeError: 'UserAvatar' object
> has no attribute '_committed'
```

`views.py`

```
def signup(request):
    ...
    user = form.save(commit=False)
    ...
    # query the avatars in the database and choose a random one for user
    avatar = UserAvatar.objects.all()
    random_avatar = random.choice(avatar)
    user.avatar = random_avatar
    ...
    user.save()
    ...
    form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {
        "title": _('Sign up'),
        'form': form,
    })

class UserAvatar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=128)
    avatar = models.FileField(_('avatar'), upload_to='media/uploads/avatar')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _('User avatars')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: Please show to us code of UserAvatar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting `attribute '_committed'` is because the `random.choice(avatar)` returns `UserAvatar` model instance not the avatar file,

you should use something like `random_avatar.model_field_name`

Answer (score 0):

As @Sumithran rightly suggest, I made a change to my code as seen below.

```
# query the avatars in the database and choose a random one for user
avatar = UserAvatar.objects.all()
random_avatar = random.choice(avatar)
user.avatar = random_avatar.avatar
```

Where `.avatar` represents the fieldname